# Safecracker File client side validation options?

Tags: safecracker, validation, safecracker-file

I'm trying to find the definitive way of **validating whether a Safecracker File custom field has been filled in or not**. The server side method using the Codeigniter validation class only semi works for me, and I'd much rather get client side validation working first anyway.

Has anyone found a reliable way of doing this? Ideally it'd be a validation library like **parsley.js**, but I can see that to use that you need to add **data-validate="parsley"** to the **form element** - something that isn't possible using Safecracker.

Any help much appreciated.

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be fairly simple in the end. You just need to add the data-validate attribute to the form tag using jquery or vanilla JavaScript. Works a treat.